# Do I have to unassign methods from the events? Why or why not?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm still in trouble of undestanding how delegates work. I've heard that if you do not unassign methods before destroying objects it can cause memory leaks in Unity.
So I have an Google Admob plugin. Instruction says that I can assign object's methods to the events, provided by the plugin.

Example:

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
// Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
    this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
```

Do I have to unassign this method before I go

```
interstitial.Destroy();
```

I've heard that if you won't do that I can cause memory leaks. Like your method of the destroyed object is still assigned to the event or something like that.
Is it true? Or I don't have to care about it, just destroy the object and it's ok.

Comment: If the object is destroyed, so are its properties and events. I have never cared about unsubscribing events while programming in Unity and neither did anyone that i know. So unless your event is called elsewhere, you should be fine, otherwise you'll get a big error telling you that you can't access it from a destroyed object.

Comment: I guess you are right. If you don't care about it - then I should do the same possibly.